# How to implement ng-repeat for different properties in object using AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs

This is my Array

```js
$scope.fieldsInfo=[];

  $scope.fieldsInfo=[
                      { 
                       "label"    :"from",
                       "required" :false,
                       "isArray"  :false,
                       "type"     : [
                                      {
                                        "label"   :"name",
                                        "type"    : "String",
                                        "required": false
                                      }
                                      {
                                        "label"   : "email",
                                        "type"    : "String",
                                        "required": true 
                                      }                     
                                    ]
                      },
                      { 
                       "label"    :"to",
                       "required" :true,
                       "isArray"  :true,
                       "type"     : [
                                      {
                                        "label"   : "name",
                                        "type"    : "String",
                                        "required": false
                                      }
                                      {
                                        "label"   : "email",
                                        "type"    : "String",
                                        "required": true 
                                      }                       
                                    ]
                      },
                      { 
                       "label"    :"subject",
                       "required" :true,
                       "isArray"  :false,
                       "type"     :"String" 
                      },
                      { 
                       "label"    :"text",
                       "required" :true,
                       "isArray"  :false,
                       "type"     :"String" 
                      },
                      { 
                       "label"    :"html",
                       "required" :true,
                       "isArray"  :false,
                       "type"     :"String" 
                      }
                    ]
```

I write following view

```html
<div class="form-group padtb5">
    <div ng-repeat="field in fieldsInfo">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 mart5">
            <div class="">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                    <label class="control-label">{{field.label}}*</label>
                </div>
                <div ng-if="angular.isArray(field.type)==true" ng-repeat="nestedField in field.type">
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                        <label class="control-label">{{nestedField.label}}*</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 marl15">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="field.objectFieldName" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 marl15">
                        <a ng-click="addMappedItem($index,'required',field)">Map</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div ng-if="angular.isArray(field.type)==false">
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 marl15">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="field.objectFieldName" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 marl15">
                        <a ng-click="addMappedItem($index,'required',field)">Map</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the above code when `type` property is array i want to repeat one div otherwise `type` property not array i want execute one more div.Now how to find the property is array or not in angular view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply bind `angular.isArray` to the scope and use it as any other function.
For example: `$scope.isArray = angular.isArray;`

Now you can use it in your html template:

```
<div ng-if="isArray(field.type)==true" ng-repeat="nestedField in field.type">
    ... your content ...
</div>

... your content ...

<div ng-if="isArray(field.type)==false">
    ... your content ...
</div>
```

Comment: do we really have to end the tag like that?

Comment: Do you mean the `</div>` tag? No, I simply added it for cosmetic reasons.

Comment: @syedfaizan I've edited my answer in hope to make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks man, i actually though the false condition was the end tag of the first div, my bad. didn't see the closing tag in the same line, sorry for the trouble

Answer (score 0):

angular.isArray not used view,
code is run:

```
<div class="form-group padtb5">
<div ng-repeat="field in fieldsInfo">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 mart5">
        <div class="">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                <label class="control-label">{{field.label}}*</label>
            </div>
            <div ng-if="field.isArray" ng-repeat="nestedField in field.type">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                    <label class="control-label">{{nestedField.label}}*</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 marl15">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="field.objectFieldName" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 marl15">
                    <a ng-click="addMappedItem($index,'required',field)">Map</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div ng-if="!field.isArray">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 marl15">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="field.objectFieldName" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 marl15">
                    <a ng-click="addMappedItem($index,'required',field)">Map</a>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: i know , but how to check property is array or not